# Getter and Setter not working

Tags: c#, .net

I currently have the following class with getters and setters as such

```
public class CustAccount
{
    public string Account { get; set; }        private string account;
    public string AccountType { get; set; }    private string accountType;

    public CustSTIOrder(Account ord)
    {
        account = ord.Account;
        accountType = ord.AccountType;
    }
}
```

Now I realize that with `public string Account { get; set; }` I do not need to declare `private string account` . Anyways now my private variable `account` contains the value but when I use `Account` to obtain the value I get a null. Any suggestions on why I am getting a null ?

Comment: OT: Funny that you comment `//end method` at the end of the class definition.

Comment: The `Account` property and the `account` variable are unrelated.

Comment: Yes, because you don't assign Account anywhere. There is no clever mechanism that maps your variable `account` to the method `Account` all by itself. If you do want to use these names, write the `get` and `set` routines out in full.

Comment: It doesn't automatically make a private variable for you. If you create a property using the short hand with {get;set;} then just use that properties name, in your case Account and AccountType with CAPITAL a's

Comment: @LastCoder: Correct, but to be a little more precise: Using an auto property *does* create a private field! However, that private field will be anonymous, i.e. hidden from the programmer, so there is no way to directly refer to it. Thus the need to do all access via the property; or implement the property explicitly, which gives you the choice which field will be used as the property's backing field.

Comment: @stakx - Well, if you want to get punctilious, I used the word "variable" instead of "field" in an attempt to show it's not created/defined (read: usable) at the source code level. But perhaps I should of used "local, class scoped, symbolic name" instead of "private variable" to be more precise.

Comment: @LastCoder, fair enough. But no need to go *that* far, it simply appears as if we had a different understanding of the term "variable". (For me, in a .NET context, a "variable" is local to a method, while a "field" is conceptually the same thing, but local to a type.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using an auto property, you should be using `Account` for all references to the property.

If you're looking to use a backing field, then you'll need to have the backing field (`account`) in the `get` and `set`.

Example:

```
public string Account 
{ 
    get { return account; }
    set { account = value; }
}        
private string account;
```

Example of use for the auto property:

```
public CustSTIOrder(Account ord)
{
    Account = ord.Account;
    // the rest
}
```

Comment: If no special need, using auto property will be simpler. You could also add an example using that.

Comment: Right, which in the first line of my answer, it says he should be using just `Account` then.

Comment: @Jeffery Khan So if I decided to go with `public string Account { get; set; }` how would I setup an initializing value like I do for private variable `private string account = "0000"` ?

Comment: By setting the Account value in your constructor. Or use the first example (not using auto properties)

Comment: That would be special implementation and in that case you would want to use a backing field.  Set the backing field to whatever the you would like the default value to be.  You could also use the constructor to assign a value to the auto property by default as well.

Comment: Haha, just like RvdK said :)

Answer (score 4):

The private field needs to be used in the property otherwise you get an [auto-implemented property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) which has a different backing store.

```
public class CustAccount
{
    private string account;
    public string Account { get {return account;} set{account = value;} }        
    private string accountType;
    public string AccountType { get{return accountType;} set{accountType = value;} }  

    public CustSTIOrder(Account ord)
    {
        account = ord.Account;
        accountType = ord.AccountType;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to connect property `Account` with field `account`:

```
private string account;
public string Account
{
   get {return this.account;}
   set {this.account = value;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just don´t use `account`, use the Property directly:

```
public class CustAccount
{
    public string Account { get; set; }        
    public string AccountType { get; set; }

    public CustSTIOrder(Account ord)
    {
        Account = ord.Account;
        AccountType = ord.AccountType;
    }
}
```

Those auto-properties are internally backed with a field, so you don´t have to write that trivial code.